# save() or saveAll()

Tags: cakephp, save

when saving data from my form I get an empty date on create field if I use save()
and it works well if I use saveAll()

does anyone knows why?

isn't it suppose to work both ways?

I'm using cake 1.3.5

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work in both ways indeed and this is really long time feature that it's working since cake1.2 or less. I would say that you messed up something, than this is core problem.

Check if the database field is DATETIME. Also check if you modify it in beforeSave.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually found out that the fields modify and create needed to be null and default null. Once I changed it was working both ways. I was not expecting a core problem but to understand a bit more the diferences between them. Thanks!